# Why does Plotly generate two plots at once (Python)?

Tags: python, plotly

I have no idea why Ploty generates two plots at once in Jupyter Notebook.  :)

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(200)
x2 = np.random.randn(200) + 2

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2']

colors = ['slategray', 'magenta']

# Create distplot with curve_type set to 'normal'
fig = ff.create_distplot([x1, x2], group_labels, bin_size=.5,
                         curve_type='normal', # override default 'kde'
                         colors=colors)

# Add title
fig.update_layout(title_text='Distplot with Normal Distribution')
fig.show()
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: I tried to run it in my environment. There is only one graph. plotly is the latest version?　The latest version is 5.6.0. If not, I recommend upgrading. It may solve your problem.

Comment: I agree that you should try upgrading plotly, and then restarting the notebook. This may also clear any artifacts

Comment: I don't have this issue on `Plotly v5.5.0`. But appending a semicolon like `fig.show();` should prevent this I guess.